# Django POST method failed to get data from ajax request

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get data from ajax request using my view class. BUt on printing the Query dict, I'm getting an empty dictionary.. I already added code related to csrf.

ajax request,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/categories/",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({"category_id": id, "category_name": name}),
    success: function(data) {
      $('#category-modal').modal('toggle');
    }
```

`urls.py`

```
  urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^categories/', CategoryView.as_view(), name='Categories'),
     ]
```

`views.py`

```
class CategoryView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'categories.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        items = CategoryQuery.get_all_categories()

        context = {
            'items': items,
        }
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query_dict = request.POST
        converted_dict = query_dict.dict()
        print converted_dict
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`request.POST` is for form-encoded data. You have JSON; you should access `request.body` and deserialize it via `json.loads`.

Comment: `while True: pass` :)

Comment: @Daniel just a small question. It shows `view didn't return an HttpResponse object`, ya I don't want my view to return any response. It just alters my db. Is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: A view does always need to return a response, that's part of the contract. You can just `return HttpResponse()`; since your Ajax call is handling the request it will do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace

```
data: JSON.stringify({"category_id": id, "category_name": name}),
```

with

```
data: {"category_id": id, "category_name": name}
```